# More information on Razor view syntax error

Tags: razor

I have a series of .cshtml "views" but occasionally I get an error like

Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at (program) (localhost/Members/?474401=:4:1)

I was wondering if it is possible to translate the query portion of the URL (?474401=:4:1) in the error to a line number in view view?